# Are there any vehicles or mounts in The Secret World?

Tags: the-secret-world

In The Secret World, are there any mounts or vehicles?

If not, are there any abilities that give increased movement speed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, there are no mounts or vehicles.

However, you **can** purchase upgrades to your *Sprint* speed from a vendor at your factions HQ. For the Illuminati at least, he's labelled as the **Mobility and Tactics Trainer**. These upgrades are called **Quickened Anima**. They come in +62.5%, +75% and +100% speed varieties (non-cumulative), are locked to faction rank and can be purchased at ranks **2**, **4**, and at a cost of 100,000, 500,000 and one million Pax Romana respectively.

Comment: Possible exception is the snowmobile you spend one part of the A Dream To Kill quest riding.

Answer (score 1):

As of patch 1.11.3 (June 03, 2015), "Custom Sprints" have been added to the game.

These are different animations / models for sprinting - and include (in this patch - more to come, we're told) the "Franken-Chopper" (a motorbike). The new custom sprints have new categories, including:

- On Foot
- Classic
- Extraordinary

The [patch notes](https://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?85802-1-11-2&p=1860312&viewfull=1#post1866104) for this addition follow:

> NEW!!
>   Custom Sprints
>   Further customize your character with all new custom sprint effects! A new collection UI houses all of your custom sprint options, and you’ll be able to select which you’d like to use primarily or let the game choose a random sprint effect upon use. Additionally, Sprint VI will be purchasable through your Faction's Advanced Faction Fixer, providing a 150% boost. The custom sprints that will debut with this feature are the Franken-Chopper motorbike, The Athlete, Fleet of Flame, and Dead Fast.